# Why WdfRequestGetFileObject allways return null?

Tags: c, driver, wdk

I am using next EvtIoWrite callback function in my file-system filter driver:

```
VOID
MyDriverEvtIoWrite(
    IN WDFQUEUE Queue,
    IN WDFREQUEST Request,
    IN size_t UnusedLength
)
{
WDFFILEOBJECT file;

    file = WdfRequestGetFileObject(Request);
    if (file != NULL)
    {
      KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "File is not null!\n"));
    }
}
```

i got allways null file object and never see "File is not null!" message. Why?

---

According to the [WdfRequestGetFileObject method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **Return value**
>
> WdfRequestGetFileObject returns a handle to the framework file object,
>   if the framework has created a file object for the specified request.
>   Otherwise, this method returns NULL. (A driver typically tests for a
>   NULL return value only if it sets the WdfFileObjectCanBeOptional bit
>   flag in the WDF_FILEOBJECT_CONFIG structure.) A bug check occurs if
>   the driver supplies an invalid object handle. Remarks
>
> **The WdfRequestGetFileObject method returns NULL if either:**
>
> Your driver > has not called WdfDeviceInitSetFileObjectConfig and specified a
>   WDF_FILEOBJECT_CLASS value that causes the framework to create file
>   objects.
>
> Another driver sent a read, write, or I/O control request to
>   your driver without first sending a request type of
>   WdfRequestTypeCreate.

But i respect this rules. Here MyDriverEvtDeviceAdd function.

```
NTSTATUS
MyDriverEvtDeviceAdd(
    IN WDFDRIVER        Driver,
    IN PWDFDEVICE_INIT  DeviceInit
    )
{
WDF_FILEOBJECT_CONFIG_INIT(
        &fileConfig,
        AAVolProcessFileCreate,
        WDF_NO_EVENT_CALLBACK,
        WDF_NO_EVENT_CALLBACK // not interested in Cleanup 
        );

    fileConfig.FileObjectClass = WdfFileObjectWdfCanUseFsContext;

    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES  attributes;

    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT(&attributes);

    WdfDeviceInitSetFileObjectConfig(DeviceInit,
        &fileConfig,
        &attributes);
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to check whether this function is called at all... This article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx shows possible reasons why WdfRequestGetFileObject can return NULL.

Comment: @ALexFaber i respect that rules.. but that don't helps.. I updated the post

Comment: Is it file system minifilter driver? Don't think WDF can be used for minifilter drivers.

Comment: @Rohan it is legacy volume filter, not minifilter

Comment: I think the reason is because your's is filter driver, so you are not creating the actual lower driver, so doing things in `MyDriverEvtDeviceAdd` will not work for lower device but rather for your device (e.g. your control device).